# Vue.js rendering v-bind:style background-image url with custom computed property does not work

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, background-image, render, computed-properties

// **Component.vue** with *computed property* - Does not work

```
<template>
<section class="background" v-bind:style="{
    'background-image': 'url(' + require(imageUrl) + ')'}"> . 
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   computed: {
     imageUrl() {
         return './path/to/image';
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

// **Component.vue** - *Direct approach* works

```
<template>
<section class="background" v-bind:style="{
    'background-image': 'url(' + require('./path/to/image.jpg') + ')'}"> . 
</section>
</template>
```

The reason for the former implementation is that I need a computed property which could be generated random every time there is a reload.

Here is the full error message for *computed property* case

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../assets/media/images/1.jpg'"

found in

---> <Background>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1733
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1728
<stack trace> // I can not post the full message since it is not allowable by the policy of stackoverflow
```

Comment: how is your result when you tried `return require('./path/to/image');` ?

Comment: It works! I am surprised. Could you explain the underlying mechanism? I

Comment: I have posted as answer and added referenced web page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change code as below.

```
   computed: {
     imageUrl() {
         return require('./path/to/image');
     }
   }
```

sorry I'm not familiar with this behavior, but as far as I searched, your problem might relates what the following page of Vue Loader says.

[Asset URL Handling | Vue Loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html)